# using SqlScriptEditorControl class for sql editor-winForms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I need to add to my project Sql editor(like the ssms use). freinds told me to use this class (`SqlScriptEditorControl`) I tried to use it, but it gave to me errors of missing `dll`

```
Error   108 The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsWindowFrameNotify2' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. C:\Users\i5\Desktop\Finish_Project\MyProject\Sqaddin\Sqaddin\Form1.cs   19  13  Sqaddin
Error   109 The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsCodeWindow' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. C:\Users\i5\Desktop\Finish_Project\MyProject\Sqaddin\Sqaddin\Form1.cs   19  13  Sqaddin
Error   110 The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsStatusbarUser' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.  C:\Users\i5\Desktop\Finish_Project\MyProject\Sqaddin\Sqaddin\Form1.cs   19  13  Sqaddin
Error   111 The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsFindTarget' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. C:\Users\i5\Desktop\Finish_Project\MyProject\Sqaddin\Sqaddin\Form1.cs   19  13  Sqaddin
Error   112 The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsWindowFrameNotify' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.  C:\Users\i5\Desktop\Finish_Project\MyProject\Sqaddin\Sqaddin\Form1.cs   19  13  Sqaddin
Error   113 The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsWindowPane' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. C:\Users\i5\Desktop\Finish_Project\MyProject\Sqaddin\Sqaddin\Form1.cs   19  13  Sqaddin
```

Where can I get this dll?
(if you used this class I will thank you very much if you will leave usfull links about this class (not this [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.ui.vsintegration.editors.sqlscripteditorcontrol.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSg9g.jpg))

this picture is for the answer of **Brien Foss**

[that what I get,I dont know where you got the second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSg9g.jpg)

I don't know where you find the second picture

Comment: if you don't like my question please, explain me why-thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those errors appear unrelated to your question. In order to get those assembly references, obtain them using Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio:

[image]

[image]

then search for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop`. It should also install those other dependencies.
As for the `SqlScriptEditorControl`, I am not sure. I will update if I can find that.

Comment: thank you for your answer, explain me please where the `Nuget Package Manager` is?

Comment: Added photo to Answer. Right click on your solution and choose "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..."

Comment: I didn't understand where you got the second picture I added picture to my question

Comment: Brien meant under `online` choose nuget.org and then type in the search box like the second picture-thank you Brien you helped me very much!

Comment: @ron yes, I’m sorry I missed your comment earlier. I am happy you were able to resolve the errors. I installed SSMS, and SQL Server data tools and still could not find the dll you were asking about. Hopefully someone can assist with that assembly in the near future.

Comment: I understood my mistake it isn't dll it's class under the dll `SQLEditors`
I have this dll only for x86 and I need it for `any cpu` or at least for 64 bits
so I get this warnning:
(in the next comment)

Comment: `Warning 15 There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "SQLEditors", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project. ` 
where can I get this dll( SQLEditors)?

Comment: Hi, Do you have answer for me

Comment: @ron I did a little research this morning and cannot find the x64 version of that assembly, even in the x64 based version of SSMS. I am not familiar enough with the product to know if there is a x64 version available anywhere for you to use. Depending on the scope of your work, you may be lucky enough to not experience runtime failures.

Comment: do you know how to add sql editor by the class `SqlScriptEditorControl`, I tried to understand it but I didn't

Comment: @ron I’m sorry no, I do not know how to use that Class